# Firebase Dynamic Link always goes to AppStore on iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a Flutter app where I want to receive DynamicLinks.

I have the following code to generate a Firebase Dynamic Link

```
    import requests

    resp = requests.post(
        url="https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key={}".format(get_secret("dynamicLinkApiKey")),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data=json.dumps({
            "dynamicLinkInfo": {
                "domainUriPrefix": "https://nutmegapp.page.link",
                "link": "https://web.nutmegapp.com/match/b20Wei3wz2DXZdtwOwF2",
                "androidInfo": {
                    "androidPackageName": 'com.nutmeg.nutmeg',
                    "androidMinPackageVersionCode": '1'
                },
                "iosInfo": {
                    "iosBundleId": "com.nutmeg.app",
                    "iosAppStoreId": '1592985083',
                }
            }
        }))
    print(resp.text)
```

the link generated always goes to AppStore on iOS even if app installed (this is an example debug link for a link generated https://nutmegapp.page.link/75W4GvLzZ41fFHUL7?d=1

This is my `ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
    <array>
        <string>Default</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:nutmegapp.page.link</string>
        <string>applinks:web.nutmegapp.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is the app-site association
https://nutmegapp.page.link/apple-app-site-association

I have a single Oauth Client ID for iOS

[image]

with the following data

[image]

I don't know what else to try